# Permutation and Combination Committee Questions

Tags: permutations, combinations

Q1. In how many ways can we select a committee of 6 persons from 6 boys and 3 girls, if at least two boys and two girls must be there in the committee?
**Given Answer: 65**

Q2. In how many ways 7 persons can be selected from 5 American, 4 British, and 2 Australian, if at least two are to be selected from each country?
**Given Answer: 100**

Can anyone help me? What should be my approach for questions of this type? (I have no idea where to start.)
Thanks!

Comment: You should include your work and thoughts so that we others can understand where you are stuck or what your confusion is.

Comment: @Probablyme I have no idea where to start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting point for the first one:  How many girls must be on the committee? (There are only two choices: 2 or 3.) If there are 3 girls on the committee, how many ways of choosing the remaining 3 boys from among the 6 available boys? (That will be 6 choose 3).

If there are 2 girls on the committee, then there are 3 ways of choosing the outcast girl.  Multiply 3 by the number of ways to choose 4 boys out of 6 (why 4?).

Finally, add the two partial answers.

$$\binom{6}{3}+3\binom{6}{4} = 65$$

Starting point for the second:  Obviously both Aussies must be on the committee.  What choices are there for the number of Brits?  (Hint -- can there be 4 Brits?  How many slots does that leave for the Americans?)

Answer (score 0):

A1: for a committee of 6 persons from 6 boys and 3 girls, first we choose 3 boys from 6 boys and 3 girls from 3 girls : $\binom{6}{3}$*$\binom{3}{3}$=20, **or** we choose 4 boys from 6 boys and 2 girls from 3 girls : $\binom{6}{4}$*$\binom{3}{2}$=45 and the final result is $20+45=65$.

A2, Try to do it